# Android Studio Flamingo opens Jetpack Compose templates directly, whereas, I wanted to use Views template. How to revert back to them?

Tags: android, android-studio

Compose Activity templates opens up directly in Android Studio Flamingo. Whereas, I want Views templates to open up first. How do I do that?